# Why didn't Darth Caedus give Tahiri Veila a Darth name?

Tags: star-wars

Jacen Solo became Darth Caedus and took Tahiri as his apprentice. Yet why didn't he give her a new name with a Darth title?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

She never embraced becoming a sith.  There is more to being a sith than just using the dark side of the force and doing bad things.  It requires first a great sacrifice of who you were.  You can no longer be that person and a sith would no longer desire to go back anyway.

For Sidious the sacrifice was easy because he did not really like who he was and had no great love for his family.

For Anakin it was much harder but the death of his mother and the visions of the potential loss of of his beloved made him willing to make the sacrifice.  But Anakin never fully embraced the path.  Instead Sidious had him do some terrible things that he felt he could never be redeemed from.  Anakin did not become a sith with the intention of becoming a powerful ruler of the galaxy but rather wanted simply to save the life of his beloved.  In the novel version it was even expressed that he hoped Amidala would understand why he had to do those things.  That is not embracing the sith but being forced down a path.  But for Sidious who never had thoughts of any thing other than how he could get more power he could not conceive how this would make a difference.  So the title of Darth Vader was conveyed without the true sacrifice of self.

Caedus choose to embrace the path of the dark side as a way to save the galaxy and his daughter from some terrible fate that is hinted at but so far as I have read not ever actually detailed.  But the difference was that Caedus knew that he could not go just half way, that to change the future he would have fully embrace the way of the sith and force time to change.

Tahiri was never more than a pawn for Caedus.  He had no intent of teaching her more than what she needed to do his bidding and to keep her begging to see the glimpses of the past.  She was even told in one of the novels that for her to become a true sith she would need to sacrifice her love for Anakin and the attachment she had for him.

Comment: Nice. I get what your saying

Comment: The fate of Allana Solo Caedus foresaw is described in details in Fate of the Jedi (by a ghost of Caedus himself). And, worth mentioning, he actually managed to change it.

Comment: @Griwes - I do not know that I would call that in detail.  Caedus did tell Luke but it was just a basic description not what I would call detailed like the vision that Luke had.

Comment: @Chad, well, Jacen told Luke what he saw, and that little detail was probably the most important part of the vision; clearly, she was also the most important part of Skywalker's and Taalon's visions. Caedus didn't describe the entire vision, but still, I'd call it "in detail", because from the point of view of the general plot, it was *really* important detail.

Comment: @Griwes - Which is why i said it was never really detailed.

Comment: I'm with Tahiri... I never got over the death of Anakin Solo, either. That event marked a downward spiral in the NJO as far as I'm concerned. When Jacen started turning evil, I threw my hands in the air and gave up on it all. I didn't struggle through Jaina going Killik just for that.